# Hatcher's problem 0.6

Tags: general-topology, homotopy-theory

> Let $X$ be the subspace of $\mathbb{R}^2$ consisting of the horizontal segment $ [0,1]\times\{0\}$ together with the vertical segments $\{r\}\times[0,1-r]$ for $r$ a rational number in $[0,1]$. Show that $X$ deformation retracts to any point in the segment $[0,1]\times\{0\}$, but not to any other point (see the preceding problem).

In the preceding problem we had that

> Show that if a space $X$ deformation retracts to a point $x\in X$, then for each neighborhood $U$ of $x$ in $X$ there exists a neighborhood $V\subset U$ of $x$ such that the inclusion map $V\hookrightarrow U$ is nullhomotopic.

which was proved via the tube lemma.

For this one I managed to show the first part i.e. that for $(x_0,0) \in [0,1] \times \{0\}$ we can deformation retract $X$ onto $(x_0,0)$ by defining two homotopies $h_1:X \times I \to X$ as $h_1((x,y),t)=(x,(1-t)y)$ and $h_2: ([0,1] \times \{0\}) \times I\to [0,1] \times \{0\}$ by $h_2((x,0),t)=((1-t)x+ tx_0, 0)$ and now putting $$h((x,y),t)= \begin{cases} h_1((x,y),2t), \ 0 \le t \le 1/2 \\ h_2((x,0),2t-1), \ 1/2 \le t \le 1 \end{cases}$$

this map is continuous as for $t=1/2$ we get that $h_1((x,y), 2t)= h_2((x,0),2t-1)$ and a deformation retraction since it keeps $x_0$ fixed and $h((x,y),0)=(x,y), h((x,y),1)=(x_0,0)$.

My problems arise at the second part of the question. I don't know how to use the preceding problem to conclude that $X$ doesn't deformation retract to any other points. I suspect that this has something to do with connectedness as $X$ reminds me a bit of the comb space, but I don't know how to incorporate that and the result from the preceding problem. What can be done here?

Comment: If $H:W\times [0,1]\to Y$ is a homotopy between $f_0$ and $f_1$, and $f_1$ has (path-)connected image, then $H$ has (path-)connected image. This is because $t\mapsto H(x,(1-t)\alpha+t)$ is a path between $H(x,\alpha)$ and $f_1(x)$. Now, from the previous lemma (specifically, with $W=V$ and $Y=U$), $X$ can only retract to a point which has a fundamental system of path-connected (not necessarily open) neighbourhoods. However, it's clear that all points of $X\setminus([0,1]\times\{0\})$ have an open neighbourhood homeomorphic to $\Bbb Q\times \Bbb R$, which does not have that local property.

Comment: It's not clear to me why all points of $X\setminus([0,1]\times\{0\})$ have an open nbhd homeomorphic to $\Bbb Q \times \Bbb R$ could you elaborate on this? I understand that if I pick any $(x,y) \in X\setminus([0,1]\times\{0\})$ and a neighborhood for $(x,y)$, then evidently this neighborhood contains other "slices" apart from the one containing $(x,y)$ and isn't path-connected as I cannot move from $(x,y)$ to any other point in $U$ via a path.

Comment: You're right, the points on the "line" $x+y=1$ do not have a neighbourhood homeomorphic to $\Bbb Q\times\Bbb R$ (but the others do): they have a neighbourhood homeomorphic to $\Bbb Q\times[0,1)$. A less convoluted way to approach the issue is: take a neighbourhood $U$ that separates $(x,y)$ from  $[0,1]\times\{0\}$. Then, the map $U\to \Bbb R$, $(r,t)\mapsto r$ has totally disconnected image, but it isn't locally constant at $(x,y)$. Therefore, $(x,y)$ has no connected neighbourhood in $U$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $x = (r,s)$ with $0 < s \le 1-r$. The set $U = X \setminus (I \times \{0\})$ is an open neigborhood of $x$ in $X$. Its path components are the sets $U_q = \{q\} \times (0,1-q]$ with $q \in I \cap \mathbb Q$.

Now assume that $x$ has an open neigborhood $V \subset U$ such that $i : V \hookrightarrow U$ is nullhomotopic. The set $V$ must a contain a point $y$ such that $y \notin U_r$ (otherwise $V \subset U_r$, which is impossible). We conclude that the restriction $j = i \mid_{\{x,y\}}: \{x,y\} \to U$ is also nullhomotopic. But $j(x) = x$ and $j(y) = y$ are contained in different path components of $U$, which prevents to find a nullhomotopy for $j$.